# ODBC SQL query to create two columns for debit and credit from one

Tags: sql, odbc

We are connecting to a proprietary ODBC source using VB .NET and using 2.0 .NET framework. We are pulling Balance field (where positive values are Debit and negative values are credit) as well as other information.

The following query **isn't possible** since case is not supported:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ACCOUNT_REF, " + _
"CASE WHEN [BALANCE] < 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END, " + _
"CASE WHEN [BALANCE] > 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END " + _
"FROM TABLE1 WHERE BALANCE <> 0"
```

Can we break the Balance column in two when working with DataSet? If so are there any examples?

We are using the following code to build our DataSet (since case is not supported in this proprietary implementation):

```
        Dim strQuery = "Select ACCOUNT_REF, BALANCE FROM TABLE1 WHERE BALANCE <> 0"
        Using connection
            Using adapter As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(strQuery, connection)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                adapter.Fill(ds)
            End Using
        End Using
```

Any help would be truly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a trailing case in a case statement: `CASE WHEN [BALANCE] < 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END` should work.

Comment: Do you mean doing something like "SELECT ACCOUNT_REF, BALANCE as DEBITS, BALANCE as CREDITS..."?

Comment: We have tried that as well - thanks - we are connecting to Sage Accounts 50.

Comment: That's right David - I am not great with SQL since I mainly work with No-SQL dbs. Is this easily done with ODBC without using CASE?

Comment: Do you have a limitation that restricts you from separating the debits from the credits in the .NET code?

Comment: I was thinking of performance, it can be achieved in .NET, but I was hoping there was an better way to do this working with Datasets before data is exported to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT Account_Ref, Balance as Debits, NULL as Credits
FROM Table1
WHERE Balance < 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Account_Ref, NULL as Debits, Balance as Credits
FROM Table1
WHERE Balance > 0
```

Clunky, but UNION or UNION ALL may be supported whereas CASE is not.

Comment: Even union doesn't work in this proprietary implementation!! Many thanks for the idea, I think I might find a way to combine the two DataSet and that will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, we have decided to use Linq to work with DataSet. Since Union is also not implemented by Sage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to see that case is not supported in ODBC under VB.NET.  I don't know much about VB.NET but maybe it's because you forgot to give a name to your Case? Try with:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ACCOUNT_REF, " + _
"CASE WHEN [BALANCE] < 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END as Debits, " + _
"CASE WHEN [BALANCE] > 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END as Credits " + _
"FROM TABLE1 WHERE BALANCE <> 0"
```

It's also possible that the delimiters `[]` are not recognised.  The official delimiter in SQL is the double quote `"` .  Howerver, as the name `Balance` has nothing of particular, you should drop these:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ACCOUNT_REF, " + _
"CASE WHEN BALANCE < 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END as Debits, " + _
"CASE WHEN BALANCE > 0 THEN BALANCE ELSE NULL END as Credits " + _
"FROM TABLE1 WHERE BALANCE <> 0"
```

Otherwise, you should use a stored procedure instead of a query string.

Comment: If this was a proper SQL DB, it would make sense, but this is Sage's own implementation for ODBC and they have confirmed that they have only implemented what they needed, since ODBC is not officially supported by them. It looks like they haven't implemented IF, CASE or UNION!!